# Displaying grid of pictures?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, controls, repeater

I wanted to use a GridView for binding a picture list. I can already do this, but I need to control how wide the grid goes.

If it was a table it would be easy like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Image 1</td>
        <td>Image 2</td>
        <td>Image 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image 4</td>
        <td>Image 5</td>
        <td>Image 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image 7</td>
        <td>Image 8</td>
        <td>Image 9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want the "gridview" to not have any real columns or anything, just simply pictures with a text descriptor below them from my database. Is the repeater control better for this?

Comment: yes repeater would be good option here. you can have more control over layout if you use that

Comment: Can you provide an example of a repeater kicking down to the next row after it has gone, say, 3 images/records wide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `DataList` control. The `DataList` control  has very useful properties called `RepeatColumns`, and  `RepeatLayout` which allow you to do what you need.

**Markup**:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <img src="<%#Eval("url") %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

**Sample Class**:

```
public class Sample
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

**Binding DataList**:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Sample> samples = new List<Sample>();
    samples.Add(new Sample() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" });
    samples.Add(new Sample() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" });
    samples.Add(new Sample() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" });
    samples.Add(new Sample() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" });
    samples.Add(new Sample() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" });
    samples.Add(new Sample() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" });

    this.DataList1.DataSource = samples;
    this.DataList1.DataBind();

}
```

**Result**: A HTML table with 2 rows with 3 columns each showing the google image.

```
<table id="Table1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe you misunderstood the OP's question. My understanding is that he does _not_ want a table layout.

Comment: My understanding is that he wants a Web Control that would do what he wants to accomplish, and used a table as a sample of the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, you want to out put the images in a form *other than* a table.

A `DataList` controls has built-in features that would make your life easier. Namely, `RepeatColumns`, and `RepeatLayout`. @Hanlet's answer explains this very well. The problem with his answer, from my understanding of your question, is that he only shows how to output as a table. Which, as I explained earlier is *not* what you are looking for. The `DataList` *can* display the output in a different way: `RepeatLayout="Flow"`. The potential problem with this approach is that the layout is rigid. It will not allow you to change how it is displayed. It uses `<span>` and `<br />` tags to display the data. While this *can* be styled using CSS, it is still somewhat limiting. Here is how the output from Hanlet's answer would look if you choose `Flow` instead of `Table` :

```
<div>
    <span id="DataList1">
       <span>
          <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
       </span>
       <span>
          <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
       </span>
       <span>
          <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
       </span>
    <br />
       <span>
          <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
       </span>
       <span>
          <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
       </span>
       <span>
          <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
       </span>
    </span>
 </div>
```

All that being said, if you want the unlimited control over the layout that a `Repeater` provides, there *is* a way to do this. Using two `Repeaters`:

**aspx code:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptRows" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptRows_ItemDataBound"> 
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img width="30px" src="<%#Eval("url") %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        </br>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**code-behind:**

```
public class ImageEntity
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public partial class DataListSample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Tuple<ImageEntity, ImageEntity, ImageEntity>> listTuples = new List<Tuple<ImageEntity, ImageEntity, ImageEntity>>();
        listTuples.Add(new Tuple<ImageEntity, ImageEntity, ImageEntity>(new ImageEntity() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" }, new ImageEntity() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" }, new ImageEntity() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" }));
        listTuples.Add(new Tuple<ImageEntity, ImageEntity, ImageEntity>(new ImageEntity() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" }, new ImageEntity() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" }, new ImageEntity() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" }));
        listTuples.Add(new Tuple<ImageEntity, ImageEntity, ImageEntity>(new ImageEntity() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" }, new ImageEntity() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" }, new ImageEntity() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" }));
        listTuples.Add(new Tuple<ImageEntity, ImageEntity, ImageEntity>(new ImageEntity() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" }, new ImageEntity() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" }, new ImageEntity() { url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" }));
        this.rptRows.DataSource = listTuples;
        this.rptRows.DataBind();
    }

    protected void rptRows_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            Repeater rptItems = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptItems");
            Tuple<ImageEntity, ImageEntity, ImageEntity> items = (Tuple<ImageEntity, ImageEntity, ImageEntity>)e.Item.DataItem;
            rptItems.DataSource = new List<ImageEntity>() { items.Item1, items.Item2, items.Item3 };
            rptItems.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, what we are doing here is splitting up the list of URLs into a List of `Tuples`. The length of the `List` is the number of "rows" in the outer `Repeater`. The number of entities in the `Tuple` is the number of "columns" in the inner Repeater.

Each time we bind an item to the outer `Repeater` (`rptRows_ItemDataBound`) , we set the datasource of the inner `Repeater` to a newly generated list of the URL entities (`ImageEntity`).

Let me know if this is clear enough, I would be happy to expand and clarify any points that are unclear.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a data list or repeater inside the item template of a listview and and in listview's layout template you can make any layout, div based , table or unsorted list